# I'm not happy about the new seating order in my class

Tags: friends

I am 13 and my place in the classroom was changed today because I was talking in the class. But the teacher made me sit next to a girl. While she was thinking about change of seat, she was muttering "hmm, I need a concentrating student to sit next to him..."

When she asked to move, she said to the girl, "Don't worry, your friends are still here around you". She also changed the seat of my best friend and made him sit with a girl behind me so that I can feel okay, but I don't want to sit next to a girl. Only two of us are sitting with a girl in the WHOLE class!

She is just very boring but she scores good marks. Other children ask me to enjoy it as she is the sexiest girl in the class.

Please tell me what to do now? Everyone and every teacher is now thinking that she is my GIRLFRIEND. (All teachers know that I am not interested in sex and love but now they are thinking negative.)

My mom teaches in the same school, and my sister is also one class below mine. Should I tell the matter to my mom? I am afraid to tell her as our WHOLE FAMILY does not think about this sex and love and girls!

Comment: This is definitely not a proper place to ask this question.

Comment: I think this question fits here just fine. If a parent had posted the question wondering how to help his child who faced this problem, we would answer it.

Comment: I would suggest a different title that tells a little more about what you are asking, like: How to deal with teenage social stress

Comment: I edited the question - does this make it better?

Comment: @MaryJoFinch I am sorry but I still disagree. According to the rules in the "about" page any question not directly related to parenting is not appropriate for this site. However, please note that I didn't cast a vote to close the question and I have even answered it. I believe that - for now - whe should treat the rules very lightly. I even mentioned it earlier [in meta here](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/a/568/6061)

Comment: @Dariusz It may not fit the rules, but it fits the intent which is to help with the raising of children. Like you, I tend toward a liberal reading of the rules.

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question once upon a time, in both cases, I feel it is a kid reaching out and asking for some "parenting" so even though it isn't a question about parenting, it seems it is related enough to let it stay to me - occasionally.  If we started getting a whole bunch of these - then we'd have to truly have a debate about it.

Comment: Now that you're 15, do they move you *away* from the other girls? ;p

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for advice about social situations, school and "what should I do" (very broad).  It isn't about parenting.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure this is the right forum for this question, but I'll give you the advice I would have given my former students.

- Putting you sitting next to a girl does not mean the teacher or other adults around will think you are dating and, honestly, even if there are some kids giving you a hard time about it - they don't actually think it means you are dating or having sex either.
- **The more upset you get about this, the more likely it is the other kids will give you a hard time**/tease you about it, or continue to tease you about it (since it sounds like they already are).  If instead, you respond with, "yeah, yeah, ha ha" in a really dull tone, they are likely to back off and stop bugging you about it pretty quickly.
- Your teacher is hoping this girl will have a good influence and help to prevent chatter.  Maybe sitting with a girl that is "boring" in your estimation, but gets good marks **could be good for you**.
- If this girl is so sexy it is distracting you from getting your work done, as embarrasing as it is, you should share this with your teacher (when the other kids are not around).  **Your teacher put you in a seat next to this girl to help you concentrate.  If it is doing the opposite, I'm guessing your teacher would like to know.**
- I understand social activities and social standings are really important to you in life right now, but that isn't how the adults around you see things so telling your mom about the fact that you got moved probably won't make her suspicious that anything about who you are and what your priorities are has changed.  **Your mom is more likely to be concerned about the fact that you were talking out of turn during class** (at least, that is how most adults I know would react - unless there is something about this you have not shared here).  I almost always recommend honesty when it comes to parents-they are the people in the world that care about you most afterall.  I just don't think she will think it as big a deal as you are concerned she will.

Good luck to you and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

Be reasonable. You were moved because of a good reason. Accept your punishment, behave better and make sure to apologize to the teacher (approach her after a lesson, when noone's looking). After a week or so ask nicely if you could go back to your seat. Promise not to talk again. **And keep the promise**.

Answer (score 4):

That's a tough predicament, to be sure. Some thoughts:

- Your teacher moved you there so you would pay attention and get your work done. So prove to her you can pay attention and get your work done, then ask to me moved.
- Kids tease. That is part of life. Unless they are being **really** mean about it, try to ignore it.
- This won't last forever. Either your teacher will eventually move you again, or your friends will get bored with teasing you about it.
- Consider this cute but boring girl could actually be quite nice. You might find you enjoy sitting next to her, but you don't have to let anyone know that!
- Getting through tough times like this is what helps us to become adults. Consider this is a test of your toughness, and tell yourself you WILL survive it!

Good luck!